# Get Remote IP Address in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to do the following based on [ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::GetIp#calculate_ip](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActionDispatch%2FRemoteIp%2FGetIp%3Acalculate_ip)

```
>> ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::GetIp.calculate_ip
```

However, I see this error:

```
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `calculate_ip' for ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::GetIp:Class>
```

So the question is, if this approach is flawed, how do I get the remote IP in the model?

Comment: `calculate_ip` is an instance method, NOT class method :)

Comment: Thank you. So what is your suggestion for getting the remote IP in the model?

Comment: Just want to say that an IP address only makes sense within the context of an http request. Therefore, I think you have to determine the IP address in the controller, not in the model. What will be the IP address when you use the model in a test or background job?

Answer (score 4):

Converting my comment into an answer:

An IP address only makes sense within the context of an http request. Therefore, you have to determine the IP address in the controller, not in the model. What will be the IP address when you use the model in a test or background job?

Inside a controller, you can get the IP address of the client with:

```
request.remote_ip
```

Now you can assign the value to a model attribute:

```
@object.ip_address = request.remote_ip
@object.save
```

Answer (score 0):

The IP address can best be determined in the context of an HTTP request, in fact Rails does that for you and provides the result in `request.remote_ip` in any instantiated controller.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    remote_ip = request.remote_ip
    # You can now pass the ip anywhere you'd like to use it
  end
end
```